# Emulator Cannot start from AVD Manager in android studio

Tags: android

Emulator Cannot start from AVD Manager in ubuntu using android studio. But when I type following code in terminal emulator is running.

Can any one help me to solve this problem to run emulator form AVD Manage.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_23
```

When I click on avd Manager a Dialog is shown with following message
Dialog Box Message Is:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  49
Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  49
Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range  for operation)
Major opc
```

Run Tab Error Message is:

```
/home/mahmud/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full   -avd Nexus_4_API_23
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  49
Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  49
Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  33
Current serial number in output stream:  34
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Comment: Why are you not using real device or genymotion emulator?

Comment: Can this error for real device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is related to libstdc++.so.6** 
go to Android sdk and can be resolved with the following command:

```
cd ~/...../sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_OLD
ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Thank you Basi for Your Answer. My Problem is solve using these command. Thank you so much